# To cut the parent-child connection in mobile view

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, responsive

I really stucked with my menu to make it in mobile view. To make it easier I put it in codepen: https://codepen.io/ipg1421/pen/OxRJRB

The menu is simple drop down. If to change it to mobile view the child item is visible but if hover -> cursor switched to parent. Moreover the last menu item (Last) goes up and hiding under child item.
My interest to make the child item as other menu item without being tied of parent item.

```
<DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
         <nav style="float: right; display: inline-block;">
            <div class="nav-handle-container">
               <div class="nav-handle"></div>
            </div>
            <ul id="nav">
               <li><a href="#">Main</a></li>
               <li class="sub"><a href="#">Parent</a>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Child</a></li>
                  </ul>             
               </li>
               <li><a href="#">Last</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </div>
      <script>
         $('.nav-handle-container').on('click', function() {
         $('#nav').toggleClass('showing');
         });
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
            .list ul {
                list-style: none;
                }
            .list li:before {
                content: '\f096';
                font-family: 'FontAwesome';
                float: left;
                margin-left: -1.5em;
                color: #1c3ba5;
            }   
            nav {
                padding-top: 25px;
                padding-right: 20px;
                }
            nav .nav-handle-container {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 30px;
                min-height: 150px;
                background: white; /* mobile container back color */
                cursor: pointer;
                -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
                display: none;
                }
            nav .nav-handle-container .nav-handle {
                height: 3px;
                width: 30px;
                background: #ff0000;
                position: absolute;
                display: block;
                /*left: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);*/
                left: calc(100% - 50px);
                top: 55px;
                }
            nav .nav-handle-container .nav-handle:before, nav .nav-handle-container .nav-handle:after {
                content: "";
                height: 3px;
                width: 30px;
                background: #ff0000;
                position: absolute;
                display: block;
                }
            nav .nav-handle-container .nav-handle:before { 
                top: -10px; 
                }
            nav .nav-handle-container .nav-handle:after { 
                bottom: -10px; 
                }
            nav ul {
                font-size: 13pt;
                list-style: none;
                background-color: white;
                overflow: hidden;
                color: black; /* color menu font */
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                text-align: center;
                -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in-out;
                transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in-out;
                }
            nav ul li {
                display: inline-block;
                border-radius: 5px;
                }
            nav ul li a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: inherit;
                display:block; /* a tag full click in menu */
                padding-right: 15px;
                padding-left: 15px;
                padding-top: 15px;
                padding-bottom: 15px;
                }
            nav ul li:hover { 
                color: white; /* color menu active font */
                background: #ff0000;
                }
            nav ul li.sub {
                border-top-left-radius: 5px;
                border-top-right-radius: 5px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 0px; 
                }
            nav ul li.sub ul {
                display: none;
                width: 300px;
                position: absolute;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                list-style-type: none;
                background: #ffffff;
                border: 1px solid #ff0000;
                border-bottom: 5px solid #ff0000;
                }
            nav ul li.sub:hover ul {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                }
            nav ul li.sub ul li {
                display: block;
                border-radius: 0px;
                }
            nav ul li.sub ul li:hover {
                background: black;
                }
            @media screen and (max-width: 760px)
            {
            nav {
                            padding-top: 0px;
                            padding-right: 0px;
                            width: 100%;
                            }
            nav .showing { 
                            max-height: 30.5em;
                            border-bottom: solid #ff0000 3px;               
                            }
            nav ul { 
                            max-height: 0px; 
                            }
            nav ul li {
                            box-sizing: border-box;
                            width: 100%;
                            text-align: right;
                            font-size: 1.0em;
                            border-radius: 0px;
                            }
            nav ul li a {
                            padding-right: 20px;
                            padding-top: 15px;
                            padding-bottom: 15px;
                            }   
            nav .nav-handle-container { 
                            display: table-row; 
                            }
            nav ul li.sub {
                            border-radius: 0px;
                            position: relative;
                            }
            nav ul li.sub ul {
                            display: block;
                            position: static;
                            max-height: none;
                            width: 100%;
                            border: 0px;
                            }
            }
```

Really thanks a lot if somebody can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi remove the postion :absolute in mobile view

use this

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      nav ul li.sub:hover ul {
       display: block;
       position: relative;
      }
    }
```

Comment: First thanks a lot. It is working and you saved me lot of time because I really stucked with this thing. I can point that under the provided answer the question is solved. I have additional things to eliminate parent hover under child hover but I suppose now i do not need additional help